# Price low - high / high - low filter PHP/Mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, filter

i am looking for a way to create a filter (select dropdown menu) that selects my products based on price.

I know this is perfectly possible with a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY price ASC 
SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY price DESC
```

But the problem is that i do not want to pass GETS to the url to select the query.

Is it possible to execute a jquery command to populate the results?

This is my select:

```
<select name="filter">
<option value="lowHigh">Price: low - High</option>
<option value="highLow">Price: High - Low</option>
</select>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are able to execute jquery which will post/get the needed vars to a .php page where the query will be executed

Comment: you can use the ajax to interact with database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no reason not to pass the sort of query through a GET.
It still remains impossible to inject/XSS, as there are only two options, without the ability of the user to add his/her own information. This is exactly what sites like eBay, Amazon and etc. do. Just define a get variable as the other responders suggested. It is highly secure and I recommend it.
If you wish to use it to save the user from refreshing, use ajax - implemented in jQuery by default.

From an html of:

```
<select id="filter">
<option value="lowHigh">Price: low - High</option>
<option value="highLow">Price: High - Low</option>
</select>
```

use a jQuery of:

```
$("#filter").change(function() {
    //Whatever ajax you wish to use
});
```

Comment: I undestand :)   
But how do i get the GET parameter in the url after selecting (for example price: low - high) in the dropdown?   
I'm really clueless on jquery!

Comment: You should add an event that listens to a new selection in the dropdown, that as a result performs a get in jquery.
This is rather easy using jQuery selectors. If you want to read about jQuery selectors you should go to: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors

To do what you wanted, select the change event of the element:
http://api.jquery.com/change/

Then on the function to perform, do the ajax query. Any more problems please let me know :)

Answer (score 1):

If i understood correctly you need to populate data somewhere in table or page when drop down changes without using get parameters.

If thats so you need something whats called **ajax**. Since you mentioned **JQuery** there is built in **ajax** functionality in jquery.

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'post',
   url: URL_TO_YOUR_PHP_SCRIPT,
   data: {
      priceFilter: $('#filter').val()
   },
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(result) {
      if (result) {
         $.each(result, function(i, item) {
            $('#your_table').append('<tr><td>'+item+'</td></tr>');
         }
      }
   }
});
```

your php script:

```
$pricefilter = $_POST['priceFilter']; //assuming you testing if its set
$pricefilter = $pricefilter == 'lowHigh' ? 'ASC' : 'DESC';

$query = "SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY price $pricefilter";
$data = $query->fetchAll(); 
//Or whatever you are using MySQL or PDO (please dont use MySQL_* functions)

echo json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to succesfully complete my script thanks to the help i have received from you guys! **(Special thanks to FunKy)**.
Looking at this piece of javascript i completely understand how it functions now. Thanks for the lesson!

This is the final script:

```
$("#filter").change(function() {
//Whatever ajax you wish to use
location.href = URL + 'index.php?action=over-ons&filter=' + $("#filter option:selected").val();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery script will still have to pass something to a server-side script to do the `SELECT`. There’s nothing stopping you doing the following:

```
<?php

$sort_dir = (isset($_GET['sort']) && $_GET['sort'] == 'desc') ? 'desc' : 'asc';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY price $sort_dir";
```